# ASP.NET Core (HttpSys) Routing works locally but not when deployed

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-mvc-routing

For some reason when I'm running my ASP.NET Core API using `HttpSys` on a windows server (through service fabric) the routing doesn't work whereas locally everything works. The thing is that the middleware works fine, so I know that the request is being processed but it's never able to hit any controller, it just defaults to my `app.run("Some 404 response")` 404 middleware. Some of my code:

**Startup.cs**

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    #region IOC
    //ommitted
    #endregion 

    services.AddAutoMapper(typeof(SomeModel));

    services.AddCors(c => 
    {
        c.AddPolicy("AllowOrigin", options => options.AllowAnyOrigin().AllowAnyHeader().AllowAnyMethod());
    });

    services.AddDbContext<SomeContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(_configuration.GetConnectionString("Dev")));

    services.AddMvc().AddFluentValidation();
}        

public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
{
    if (env.IsDevelopment())
    {
        app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        IdentityModelEventSource.ShowPII = true;
    }

    //Eliminating that auth is the problem
    //app.UseAuthentication(); 

    if (env.IsProduction())
    {
        app.UseHsts();
        app.UseHttpsRedirection();
    }

    app.UseCors("AllowOrigin");
    app.UseMvcWithDefaultRoute(); //tried this instead of below. No luck

    //app.UseMvc();

    app.Use((context, next) =>
    {
        if (context.Request.Path.Value == "" || context.Request.Path.Value == "/")
        {
            context.Response.ContentType = "text/plain";
            return context.Response.WriteAsync("We're running!");
        }

        return next.Invoke();
    });

    app.Run(context =>
    {
        context.Response.StatusCode = 404;
        context.Response.ContentType = "application/json";

        return context.Response.WriteAsync("{ \"message\": \"Not found\" }");
        });
    }
}
```

**Program.cs:**

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    using (var scope = host.Services.CreateScope())
    {
        var services = scope.ServiceProvider;
        try
        {
            var context = services.GetRequiredService<SomeContext>();
            DbInitializer.Initialize(context);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            logger.Error(ex, "An error occured while seeding the database");
        }
    }

    host.Run();
}
```

```
public static IWebHost CreateWebHostBuilder(string[] args)
{
    IHostingEnvironment env = null;

    var builder = 
        WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
        .UseStartup<Startup>()
        .ConfigureAppConfiguration((hostingContext, config) =>
        {
           env = hostingContext.HostingEnvironment;
        })
        .UseHttpSys(options =>
        {
            if (!env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                options.UrlPrefixes.Add("https://*:30010/BasePathOfAPI/");
            }
            else
            {
                options.UrlPrefixes.Add("http://localhost:5000/BasePathOfAPI/");
            }
        })
        .ConfigureLogging(b =>
        {
            b.AddApplicationInsights("id here");
        })
        .UseNLog()
        .Build();

    return builder;
}
```

So the setup is almost similar apart from the UrlPrefixes. The fact that I can both through a gateway and on the windows server call `https://somehost/BasePathOfAPI/` and get the message `We're running!` displayed in the browser tells me that the API is up and running but it's simply not able to hit any of the controllers if I try. One example of a controller:

```
[Route("api/{someNumber:int}/Home")]
[ApiController]
public class HomeController: ControllerBase
{
    //ctor and props ommitted

    [HttpGet("GetSomeData")
    [ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.200OK)]
    public async Task<IActionResult> GetSomeData()
    {
        //implemenetation
    }
}
```

Now, the url I'm using to try and get to the above controller is:

```
https://somehost/BasePathOfAPI/api/1234/Home/GetSomeData
```

Which returns in a 404 message: not found, however if I locally run:

```
http://localhost:5000/BasePathOfAPI/api/1234/Home/GetSomeData
```

It works fine.

Not sure where I'm going wrong, maybe something with the `UrlPrefixes` but should I then be able to get to the middleware if that's incorrect? 
Maybe something with the routing, but then why does it work locally?

Comment: https://*:30010/BasePathOfAPI/ where is your port number  (30010)  in your production url ?

Comment: The gateway will use the port. If I do it locally on the server with the port number it's the exact same result. I am calling my app because I'm seeing my hardcoded 404 message and also if no path is given I see my "We're running!" message

Comment: can you check this "Only HTTP URL prefixes are valid. Kestrel doesn't support HTTPS when configuring URL bindings using UseUrls" 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/servers/kestrel?tabs=aspnetcore2x&view=aspnetcore-2.2#when-to-use-kestrel-with-a-reverse-proxy

Comment: I'm not using Kestrel, I'm using Http.sys where it is allowed to have https in UrlPrefix as far as I understand

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Solved - The full path base must be added to the UrlPrefix and the urlacl registration so

```
netsh http add urlacl url=https://*:30010/BasePathOfAPI/ user="NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE"
```

and in addition to this as controllers are in another dll, the assembly must be referenced in the ConfigureServices method:

```
services.AddMvc().AddApplicationPart(typeof(SystemController).Assembly)
```

These two fixes made it work

Answer (score 1):

This may be an issue with the weak wildcard in the UrlPrefix.

Try this for the production binding instead:-

```
options.UrlPrefixes.Add("https://somehost:30010/BasePathOfAPI/");
```

Where `somehost` is the FQDN of the machine.

Comment: The host is dynamic behind the gateway, as it's the IP of nodes that the app is running on. But if the host was the issue then I shouldn't be able to hit my app in the first place right?

Comment: Perhaps try the strong wildcard then... `options.UrlPrefixes.Add("https://+:30010/BasePathOfAPI/");`. I've just had similar problems before with it not matching routes with the weak wildcard; probably to do with URL reservations.

Comment: I tried that just now, still just jumps to the 404 middleware.It's like it's not routing at all but still manages to get the request into the application.

Comment: How sure are you that it's hitting *your* 404 middleware and not some other process? That's got me before... I thought it was my app responding and it was something else. Also, just to be clear, in your question you say you're trying to hit `https://somehost/BasePathOfAPI/api/1234/Home/GetSomeData`, but your UrlPrefix is on port 30010... is that just a typo?

Comment: I'm 100% sure as I've tried to change it around and observe that the text changes both for "We're running!" and the not found one as well. It's definitely hitting my app. The port is left out because the gateway will forward it with a port number. However the exact same behaviour can be observed if you log onto the VM where the app is running and execute https ://localhost:30010/BasePathOfApi/api/1234/Home/GetSomeData

Comment: So it works on the server (from local) if you go to `localhost:30010`... you get the "We're running!" (which is text from your app), but don't get the route working? A thought, when you access locally.. is it http or https? Have you tried removing all the other stuff like `UseHttpsRedirection` to get back to basics and see if it works?

Comment: Yeah it works in the sense that I'm seeing my custom messages.So exact same behaviour as if I just go through the public url which then goes through the gateway. This is all https. On my local machine I'm using http, and here everything works so you have a point that it might be related to that.
To be clear: Gateway + localhost on vm = HTTPS and routing doesn't work. My own machine with localhost = HTTP with port 5000, where everything works

Comment: Normally I would say break it down into pieces and try to get each bit working in its own right, however, I've had issues where proxies do things to the X-Forwarded-* headers and ASP.NET gets confused. Proxy aside, if you can get it working on your prod server and access a route on your prod server, then it will come down to being an issue with your proxy and what hostname ASP.NET things you're trying to access in your app (hence my original answer about UrlPrefixes)

Comment: I get what you're saying but I've eliminated the issue that it's to do with the proxy because calling it on the server itself has the exact same issue as if I go through the proxy. Tried both. That's why I'm super confused. But yeah I'm trying to remove parts now until it works!

Comment: For example, proxies aside... I had one configured with `http://localhost` and I couldn't access it locally using `http://127.0.0.1`... I had to use `http://localhost` with curl otherwise it wouldn't route...

Comment: Also, maybe (hopefully) some helpful reading... https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/proxy-load-balancer?view=aspnetcore-2.2